# I am planning on getting a tattoo that says “Relentless” in Chinese. Would anyone here be able to tell me the correct characters?

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters

I am planning on getting a tattoo that says “Relentless” in Chinese. Would anyone here be able to tell me the correct characters? Google translate's result is 狠, which also carries the meaning of "ruthless", not a very positive character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relentless --> work hard, not relent --> 努力不松懈

I suggest a more idiomatic phrase: **努力不懈**

- 努力(strive: *make great efforts to achieve one's goal*)
- 不懈 (indefatigable: *of a person or their efforts persisting tirelessly.*)

Comment: Hi Tang Ho, I appreciate the response greatly. To the idiomatic phrase that you suggested, what does each character mean one by one?

Comment: Most of the Chinese words are two-characters compound words. Each of the four characters has multiple meanings, 努(strive)力(force)不(not)懈(relent); - 努力(strive)不懈(not relent);

Comment: I see, that makes a lot more sense to me now. When it comes to the phrase as a whole though, how would I describe the four characters all at once? Would I just say it means "Relentless" or would there be a different term instead?

Comment: What would I say bro?

Answer (score 0):

How are you relentless?

A relentless enemy?
A crashing bore?

> relent:  Figurative sense of "become less harsh or cruel, soften in
> temper" is recorded from 1520s; the notion probably is of a hard heart
> melting with pity.

relentless: without relent

无休止: no relent
不懈的: never idle
毫无减弱: never soften
日新月异: daily renewal, monthly change
坚持不懈：persevere unremittingly

Tattoo tata!